# Set the value of multiple form elements with the same ID, Paypal

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm trying to figure out a paypal issue.

I have multiple 'buy now' buttons on the page and I need to set a value for all of the buttons.

The 'buy now' button elements all have the same ids.

Each 'buy now' button represents a licence range, so there's '1-5', '6-10', '11-20, etc. I have a list of versions, they are dropped in the page as follows in a loop:

```
$strWeights1 .= "<span id='1".$row['Tag']."' onclick='select_weight(this.id)' class='linkoff'>". $row['Tag'] . "</span> | ";
```

I might be over thinking this, but what would be the best way to set the selected 'version' in all the 'buy now' buttons?

I am thinking of using the paypal variable 'item_number'

Cheers

Like I've said the buttons are from PayPal, I can't control the naming of there fields, hence the problem I'm up against.

OK, so the select weight function just makes the span work like a href tags, turning on and off the 'buttons'.

```
function select_weight(value){

        value = value.substr(1);

        document.forms["fontweight"]["fw"].value = value;
        //this.forms["item_number"].value = value;

        thin = document.getElementById('1Thin');
        if(thin != null){
            thin.className = "linkoff";
            thin = document.getElementById('2Thin');
            thin.className = "linkoff";
        }
        light = document.getElementById('1Light');
        if(light != null){
            light.className = "linkoff";
            light = document.getElementById('2Light');
            light.className = "linkoff";
        }
        book = document.getElementById('1Book');
        if(book != null){
            book.className = "linkoff";
            book = document.getElementById('2Book');
            book.className = "linkoff";
        }
        medium = document.getElementById('1Medium');
        if(medium != null){
            medium.className = "linkoff";
            medium = document.getElementById('2Medium');
            medium.className = "linkoff";
        }
        bold = document.getElementById('1Bold');
        if(bold != null){
            bold.className = "linkoff";
            bold = document.getElementById('2Bold');
            bold.className = "linkoff";
        }
        heavy = document.getElementById('1Heavy');
        if(heavy != null){
            heavy.className = "linkoff";
            heavy = document.getElementById('2Heavy');
            heavy.className = "linkoff";
        }
        black = document.getElementById('1Black');          
        if(black != null){
            black.className = "linkoff";
            black = document.getElementById('1Black');
            black.className = "linkoff";
        }

        //alert(value);
        fontweight1 = document.getElementById('1'+value);
        fontweight2 = document.getElementById('2'+value);
        fontweight1.className = "linkon";
        fontweight2.className = "linkon";}
```

This is the code for the buttons, it is in the page about 16 times, the 'item_name' and  'hosted_button_id' change each time:

```
<form target=\"paypal\" action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return validateForm()\" >
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"_s-xclick\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hosted_button_id\" value=\"xxxxxxxx\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"item_name\" value=\"".$strProdName." : 1-5 terminals \">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"item_number\" value=\" [set this value] \">
            <input type=\"image\" onMouseOver=\"this.src='images/paypalon.png';\" onMouseOut=\"this.src='images/paypaloff.png';\" src=\"images/paypaloff.png\" border=\"0\" name=\"submit\" alt=\"PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.\">
            <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://ipn.php'>
        </form>
```

I've been thinking about how to sort this out. Can I use the form validation function to access the specific form and set the value that way? I have been trying this with any success.

```
function validateForm(form)
{
    var x=document.forms["fontweight"]["fw"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Hold on a moment, you need to select a weight before hitting the ‘Buy’ button.");
        return false;
    }
    else{

        field = document.form;
        //this.form['item_number'].value = x;
        alert(field['item_name'].value);
        return false;
    }
}
```

the form tag has this call in it

```
onsubmit="return validateForm(this.form)"
```

Am I on the right track> or should I ditch it?

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id

Comment: all elements must have different ID, it`s wrong to use the same ID for many elements, you can use class for many elements, but not ID.

Comment: Please show us more code, especially the buttons and the `select_weight` function. That code to generate some `span` tags doesn't help much

Comment: I've added more of the code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I've sorted this out. I've moved the validation to the button using 'onClick'. I'm passing (this.form) and using this to get to the element.

While I appreciate that multiple IDs with the same name is wrong, it's the PayPal buttons are are named the same not my code.